# Using opencv with javacv in web application

Tags: java, opencv, web-applications, javacv

I am making a web application which uses Face Detection in which user is asked to take a picture from webcam or upload from his computer at time of Registration.

After that store it on my server and then when user log in website again then use Face Recognition for Login to the website.Now am thinking of using opencv with javacv to implement it in my Java web application.

Where can I get about it in Java? Not in any other wrapper language like Python.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through [this chapter](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui08/).